# Iterate thru on database tables and delete some of them based on the name of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hello I would like to loop thru my database tables and delete the ones that I don't need. Also I would like this code to be a stored procedure.

I would like to iterate thru on this select's table_name_to_be_deleted:

```
SELECT name as table_name_to_be_deleted
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE 7=7 
      and name like 'x_%' 
      and modify_date< dateadd(day,-10,GETDATE())
```

And drop every table that I have in the table_name_to_be_deleted column

```
drop table *variable*
```

Sorry no minimum viable product as I am not that familiar in T-SQL, but I would much appreciate your help!

Comment: Take a full backup first of all...

Comment: @jarlh I don't need, these are archive dump

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. I can perhaps understand doing this as a one off process but as you want an SP, that means a regular process. Why do you need to do this? Smells like a large design flaw.

Comment: @Larnu we are archiving a tables that we create every day and put the archive date in the name of the table, the reason why we not creating a big table from these archive tables is that the tabels what we create are constantly changing. I know that this is not a good solution but this is what we have, so i would like to delete the tables that are old, to keep my DB clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL to do this. Making use of the `sys.schemas` and `sys.tables` you could do something like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DeleteArchives @OlderThan date AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF +
                             N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name])
                      FROM sys.schemas s
                           JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                      WHERE t.[name] LIKE N'x[_]%'
                        AND t.modify_date < @OlderThan
                      FOR XML PATH (N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

END;
```